# hide / show div if less or greater than a certain number using jQuery

Tags: jquery, show-hide

I'm trying to us jQuery to hide or show something if less than or greater than 20000

This is the table element I'm using. The td.weight is populated dynamically using a custom shipping calculator. There's a max weight returned by the api of 20000 lbs and then it zero's out.

I'm attempting to notify the user by hiding or showing a div if their calculated weight is over 20000 lbs or less than 20000 lbs

Show div.shipping-weight if this output:

```
<td class="weight"> 20000 <small><em> lb's </em></small><br>
<div class="shipping-weight"><small>*Note: Up to 20,000 lbs max.  For shipping requirements over 20,000 lb's call our</small><br>
<small>PRICING HOTLINE: 1-877-444-444 </small>
</div>
</td>
```

Hide div.shipping-weight if this output:

```
<td class="weight"> 19456 <small><em> lb's </em></small><br>
<div class="shipping-weight"><small>*Note: Up to 20,000 lbs max.  For shipping requirements over 20,000 lb's call our</small><br>
<small>PRICING HOTLINE: 1-877-444-444 </small>
</div>
</td>
```

Here is what I have so far.

```
    $('td.weight').filter(function(index){
return parseInt(this.innerHTML) > 20000;
    }).show('.shipping-weight');
```

Here's a [jsfiddel](http://jsfiddle.net/fNsNj/1/)

*Revision:

This doesn't seem to fire in my ajax request but works on jsfiddle.  I'm using keyup and livequery to make the request. As follows:

```
        $('.input-mini').keyup().livequery('change', function () {
                url = $(this.form).attr('action');
                data = $(this.form).serialize();
                $.post(url, data, function () {
                        $('#checkout').load('/store/checkout_table');
                        $('#checkout_form').attr('action', url);
    $('.weight').filter(function(index){
        var num = parseInt(this.firstChild.textContent);
        return num >= 20000;
    }).find('.shipping-weight').show();

            $.cookie('all_cookie', null);

                });
                return false;
        });
```

Comment: Provide a jsfiddle.net demo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Working solution](http://jsfiddle.net/fNsNj/1/):

```
$('.weight').filter(function(){
    var num = parseInt(this.firstChild.textContent);
    return num >= 20000;
}).find('.shipping-weight').show();
```

Note: `this.firstChild` is the first DOM node inside `.weight`, e.g. the text node `" 19456 "`.

Comment: That's perfect!  It works in the fiddle but I left out one element.  I'm doing an ajax call on the table so, once it's loaded and the value is changed to less than 20000, the result of the initial jQuery is still visible. Maybe I should include the js inside the ajax requested page.  Thanks again!  I would vote this up, but I'm not allowed to yet.

Comment: _"Maybe I should include the js inside the ajax requested page"_. Best you include this toggle functionality in your ajax success handler ;).

Comment: Adding it into the ajax requested page with document ready did the trick.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="weight"> <SPAN>**200230**</SPAN> <small><em> lb's </em></small><br>
            <div class="shipping-weight"><small>*Note: Up to 20,000 lbs max.  For shipping requirements over 20,000 lb's call our</small><br>
                <small>PRICING HOTLINE: 1-877-444-444 </small>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>


<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function() {
         var weight = parseInt($('td.weight span').html().replace(/\*/g, ''));
        if(weight >= 2000){ 
            $('div.shipping-weight').show();
        } else {
            $('div.shipping-weight').hide();
        }

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work but I'm having issues removing the div upon ajax reload.  I might have to edit my question.  I'm using a keyup function on an input to re-load the page via ajax request.  For some reason, on reload, the js wont trigger on the second load.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $('.weight').filter(function () {
      var weight = parseInt(this.firstChild.textContent);
      if (weight >= 20000) {
        $('.shipping-weight').show();
      } else {
        $('.shipping-weight').hide();
      }
   });
```